# AMPscript where substring == ??? in if statement

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

In the code below I'm not getting into the second If statement even when the @sfid (passed in from the url) variable starts with 00Q.  When the page is loaded I can see the two outputs that have 00Q for @Startswith, but always Contact for @leadString.

Where have I made what must be a simple mistake?

```
    %%[
  if @rowCount < 1 then

     SET @Startswith = Substring(@sfid, 1, 3) 

        If @Startswith(@sfid, 1, 3)=='00Q' then
            set @leadString = "Lead"

            else
        set @leadString = "Contact"

        endif
    output(concat("Startswith is: ", @Startswith))
    output(concat("leadString is: ", @leadString))

        UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(@leadString, @sfid,
        "Double_opt_in_date__c", Format(DateParse(now(),1), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000"),
        "Double_opt_in__c", "True")


  endif]%%
```

Comment: this line seems wrong @Startswith(@sfid, 1, 3)=='00Q' then  should possibly be @Startswith=='00Q' then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error on the following line:

```
If @Startswith(@sfid, 1, 3)=='00Q' then
```

It should be:

```
If @Startswith =='00Q' then
```

Refer to the [AMPScript Language Elements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm) for an understanding on how the language operates.

Try this:

```
%%[

if @rowCount < 1 then

 set @Startswith = Substring(@sfid, 1, 3) 

    if @Startswith == '00Q' then
      set @leadString = "Lead"
    else
      set @leadString = "Contact"
    endif

    output(concat("Startswith is: ", @Startswith))
    output(concat("leadString is: ", @leadString))

    UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(@leadString, @sfid,
      "Double_opt_in_date__c", Format(DateParse(now(),1), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000"),
      "Double_opt_in__c", "True")
endif
]%%
```

Comment: That was it, thank you.  I guess I had stared at it too long.